# How to find the average of words using the characters of the JTextArea inputted string

Tags: java, swing, average, jtextarea, string-length

I am writing a program for an assignment using JTextArea to have the user manually input text then I/the program computes simple statistics. The problem I am having is when I'm computing the average length of each word inputted, it does not compute correctly (ie: words: 2, characters: 6, average length: 3, but my program currently says 3.5).

I've tried (double) and (float) and nothing in front of (count++)/words.length to see if it was the program's rounding errors and that doesn't effect the output at all.

I also thought it might be because it is count the spaces '  ' so I found on a snippet of code that excludes the space in counting the characters of the inputted string. @ https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-count-characters-in-a-string-in-Java-without-using-charcount

I'm still fairly new to Java, and help would be appreciated! I feel like it's a simple solve, just something I'm not seeing yet. I've include the part of the code that pertains to this, and everything not included is me creating the text field, frame, and buttons, etc...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String parsedString = inputText.getText();
        String delims = "[1234567890.,?!()*\\s]+";
        String words[]=parsedString.split(delims);

        char [] ch = parsedString.toCharArray();
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            if (ch[i]!=' '){
            count++;
            }
        }

        wordCounter.setText("Words inputed: " + words.length);
        wordCharacters.setText("Characters:" + count++ );
        wordAverage.setText("Average Length: " + (float) (count++)/words.length ); 

    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you get out your debugger and keep an eye on the value of `count` while you single-step through those last three `setText` calls. Then ask yourself "Why did `count` change?".

Comment: Hey @KevinAnderson I'm using JCreator LE (recommend IDE from my course) which I found out doesn't have a debugger.. any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: Why are you dividing count++ by the word count rather than just count

Comment: Poor-man's debugger: insert `System.out.println(...)` statements into your code at strategic points to display variable values, track program flow, etc.  Better yet, find a better IDE...

Comment: Yes, the more I code the more I realize I need to find a better IDE... I'll start with the print statements and see what's happening there

Comment: Another "top tip":  add `private static final boolean DEBUG = true;` at the top of your class, then surround any debugging code you add with `if (DEBUG){ /* debug code here */ }`.  This lets you turn the debug code on and off just by changing the value of the `DEBUG` variable between `true` and `false`; also makes it easier to spot the "debug-only" code and remove it without accidentally disturbing your "real" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trim the `parsedString` before use it in the code. It removes leading and trailing spaces in the string.

Here `wordCharacters.setText("Characters:" + count++ );` and `wordAverage.setText("Average Length: " + (float) (count++)/words.length );` here `count++` is unnecessary because it increments the count calculated from for loop. It is the issue in your code. Please check below answer.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String parsedString = inputText.getText().trim();
    String delims = "[1234567890.,?!()*\\s]+";
    String[] words = parsedString.split(delims);

    char[] ch = parsedString.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        if (ch[i] != ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    wordCounter.setText("Words inputed: " + words.length);
    wordCharacters.setText("Characters:" + count);
    wordAverage.setText("Average Length: " + (float) (count) / words.length);
}
```